# returning a string from resultset

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i've a problem in returning a string from a connection to a database. It says that return_statement "might not have been initialized", of course, but if i put the returning point inside the try, it says "there's no return in the object". I'm a bit noob please don't blame me :/

```
import java.sql.*;

public  class DbConnector {

   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_ADDRESS = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/java_prog";

   String query;

     static final String USER = "root";
     static final String PASS = "root";





  public static String dbAsker (String query){
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String return_statement;

     try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_ADDRESS,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query

      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);



     return_statement = rs.toString();

      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
       stmt.close();
      conn.close();

   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
       try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");

   return return_statement;



  }
}
```

Comment: Try this String return_statement="";

Comment: `Statement stmt` not initialized `stmt= conn .createStatement();` missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484550/java-variables-not-initialized-error

Answer (score 0):

Use  `String return_statement = null;` or `String return_statement = "";` instead of  `String return_statement;`. If exception was happened, return_statement hasn't got any value when using in return, it's impossible in Java.